# How can I send a 997 ACK through Logic Apps

Tags: azure, edi, x12

I am trying to send a 997 ack through logic apps. I have managed to generate the JSON through get the FA returned when decoding a message. I then pass this over to another app which then tries to encode it to X12.

The problem comes here, the app throws an error saying that it cannot find the relevant schema in the agreement, but I am unable to add a 997 schema to the agreement as it doesn't show up in the UI. I have the schema in the portal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone needs this in the future, the answer is to first enable the FA expected within the Receive Agreement. Then within your Logic App, when you're iterating through good and bad messages you create another ForEach and iterate through 'GeneratedAcks'. Then add an Encode X12 step, pass in the AckPayload and the name of the agreement. This will give you your 997 EDI, you then simply need to send it over to the customer by the usual means, in my case AS2 and HTTP. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5QJ1S.png)